# Erratic keyboard behavior when paired with a particular monitor

Tags: keyboard, display, hardware-failure

My keyboard works normally if plugged in to another PC, but behaves erratically on mine.

...days of troubleshooting skipped...

Then I discovered that **if I change my monitor, the keyboard works normally**.

Both monitors are connected using VGA. I tried plugging the "supposed problem" monitor to the PC's HDMI port using an adapter but the problem persists.

It is a USB Keyboard. Currently I don't have USB to PS/2 adapter to test. Mouse is also USB but it is working fine. No other USB devices plugged.

By erratic behavior I mean: skipping letters, slow response, and repeating letters by itself.

Any thoughts of what might be the issue?

Thank you.

Edited:

- Tried plugging the monitor and PC to a different wall power outlet.
- This also happens in BIOS

Comment: entirely without much basis, I wonder if its earthing related. On a keyboard I recently took apart, it looked a lot like all the keys had a common earth - and its possible the monitor, PC and keyboard share a earth, and faulty earth might do it. I'd try troubleshooting the keyboard with a powered USB hub in between.

Comment: I tried plugging the monitor & PC to different power outlet (different wall). Will this resolve the earth problem if it does causes it? Don't have a powered USB around right now.

Comment: Generally no - I think building share a earth across all plugs. I'm suspecting a *fault* in the monitor that's causing trouble. That said, this is one of those issues that's potentially restricted to specific combinations of hardware, and I'm being entirely speculative ._..